# Kill ssh or\and remote process from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I am trying to run the following command as part of the bash script which suppose to open ssh channel, run the program on the remote machine, save the output to the file for 10 sec, kill the process, which was writing to the file and then give the control back to bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh hostname '/root/bin/nodes-listener > /tmp/nodesListener.out </dev/null; sshpid=!$; sleep 10; kill -9 $sshpid 2>/dev/null &'
```

Unfortunately, what it seems to be doing is starting the program: nodes-listener remotely, but it never gets any further and it doesn't give control to the bash script. So, the only way to stop the execution is to do Ctrl+C.

Killing ssh doesn't help (or rather can't be executed) since the control is not with bash script as it waits for the command within the ssh session to complete, which of course never happens as it has to be killed to stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the command line that you're running on the remote system:

```
/root/bin/nodes-listener > /tmp/nodesListener.out </dev/null
sshpid=!$
sleep 10
kill -9 $sshpid 2>/dev/null &
```

You should change it to this:

```
/root/bin/nodes-listener > /tmp/nodesListener.out </dev/null & <-- Ampersand goes here
sshpid=$!
sleep 10
kill -9 $sshpid 2>/dev/null
```

You want to start `nodes-listener` and then kill it after ten seconds. To do this, you need to start `nodes-listener` as a background process, so that the shell which is executing this command line to move on to the next command after starting nodes-listener. The `&` in your command line is in the wrong place, and would apply only to the `kill` command. You need to apply it to the nodes-listener command.

I'll also note that your `sshpid=!$` line was incorrect. You want `sshpid=$!`. `$!` is the process ID of the last command started in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the ampersand after the first command, then put the remaining commands onto the next line:

```
ssh hostname -- '/root/bin/nodes-listener > /tmp/nodesListener.out </dev/null &
sshpid=$!; sleep 10; kill $sshpid 2>/dev/null'
```

Btw, ssh is returning after all commands had been executed. This does mean it will close the allocated pty as well. If there are still background jobs running in that shell session, they would being *killed* by `SIGHUP`. This means, you can probably omit the explicit `kill` command. (Depends on whether `nodes-listener` handles SIGHUP and SIGTERM differently). Having this, you could simplify the code to the following:

```
ssh hostname -- sh -c '/root/bin/nodes-listener > /tmp/nodesListener.out </dev/null &
sleep 10'
```

Comment: Thank you. My command is part of the bash script. Why do I need to specify that it is bash explicitly?

Comment: Your command runs remotely, triggered by ssh. As I told, ssh will not start a shell and execute commands in it. It will simply use `execve` (or friends) to execute the command. But your command is not more ore less a shell script. That's why you need to execute it in a shell

Comment: It complains: "sh: bash: not found"  if I run it with -- bash -c

Comment: If bash isn't installed on the remote machine, use `... -- sh -c ...`

Comment: It started the program execution (nodes-listener), but it never gave the control back to my machine, so that I have to kill ssh within bash file on my machine with Ctrl+C.

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you try my update? Please use it as it is, with the newline.

Comment: It gave control back to my bash file, but didn't kill the process on the remote machine.

Comment: Remove the `2>/dev/null` and listen to what `kill` says

Comment: @hek2mgl Actually, `ssh` does use a shell to execute the command on the remote system. All of the ssh command-line arguments that are deemed to be part of the remote command are concatenated into a string, passed to the remote system, and executed as a shell command.

Comment: @Kenster The man page clearly states: `If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.`. Where do you have your information from?

Comment: I have my information from trying it, and from reading the source code while researching the issue previously. The man page just says "instead of a login shell". That doesn't preclude using a shell to run the command.

Comment: @Kenster I've investigated it. If you are passing a single command, with no redirection or other shell syntax, to ssh, then it will *not* getting wrapped in a shell. If you are passing shell syntax it *will* getting wrapped in a shell. (By whatever magic) If you ask me, the man page should mention this, also I would like to have control over this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this by pushing the shell script to the remote machine and executing it there. It is actually less tidy and relies on space being available on the remote computer.

Since my remote machine is a small physical device, the issue of the space usage is important (even for the tiny amount of space required in this case).

```
/root/bin/nodes-listener > /tmp/nodesListener.out </dev/null &
sshpid=!$
sleep 20
sync
# killing nodes-listener process and giving control back to the base bash
killall -9 nodes-listener 2>/dev/null && echo "nodes-listener is killed"
```